# Preventing a static method in base class from being called through derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, static-methods

I have a Base class, and a Derived template that inherits from it.  Both of these define a static method `calculateSize()` but with different method signatures.  (Both are also instanced as objects; Base isn't just an interface.)

```
class Base{
public:
    static size_t calculateSize(size_t payload); 
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base{
public:
    // sloppy fixo to prevent Base::calc() from being called
    static size_t calculateSize(size_t){ assert(0); return calculateSize(); }  
    
    // correct method to call
    static size_t calculateSize();
};
```

The Base class's version of this method would give a wrong answer if called for a Derived type, so I want to prevent it from accidentally being called through `Derived::calculateSize(sz)`.  How would this typically be accomplished?  (I currently have a method with the same signature in `Derived` that asserts if called, this feels kinda hacky though...)

Comment: `I have a Base class, and a Derived template that inherits from it.` - shouldn't it be `class Derived: Base` in this case?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind - it should, I miswrote the example, thank you for catching that

Comment: You can't make the base class version private?

Comment: @MartinYork - sadly no, `Base::calcSize(arg)` has to be public since Base objects are useful.  The Derived version only has a different signature because the type provides enough info, so there's no need for a parameter, via `Derived<Type>::calcSize()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `calculateSize` in the derived class, it will hide `calculateSize` in the base class, so you can simply just not have anything:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    static size_t calculateSize();
};

// Error: no function that takes an argument
size_t result = Derived<int>::calculateSize(1);
```

If you don't have something to hide it or you want it to be more clear that you shouldn't call it with the base classes signature, you can `= delete` it:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    // Explanatory comment here
    static size_t calculateSize(size_t) = delete;
    static size_t calculateSize();
};

// Error: trying to use deleted function
size_t result = Derived<int>::calculateSize(1);
```

Comment: Ah!  I didn't realize I could delete methods (beyond like, copy ctors or whatever).  Generating a compiler-time error is precisely what I wanted, thank you!